# How to find the Minimal positive integer which not in a given array in lower time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

given an array, how to figure out the Minial positive integer with high performance(memory usage is not considered), and the integer should not in the array, and there may exists repeatitive positive and negative nums in the given array.

for example, given an array:

case 1:

```
when l = [-4, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]  
return 1
```

case 2:

```
when l = [-3, -9, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5]
return 4
```

I have tried like this (python code):

```
def find_min_not_in(l):
    min = -sys.maxint
    for i in l:
       min = i if i > 0 and i < abs(min)
    if min <= 0 or min >= 2:
       return min = 1
    while min in l:
       min = min+1
    return min
```

but it's not the best because `in` op is scanning the whole array time and time  again. I want a low time complexity solution.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Sorry, but after 4+ years here, I would expect a _better_ question, don't you think?

Comment: Not only that, you should proofread your question. Spelling errors ("repeatitive"). "Not in the array"... do you mean "not *be* in the array"?. And please clarify "high performance". Memory usage, or run-time? You should have a working solution first before thinking about optimizing.

Comment: sorry for the grammer errors, guys,  I am not a english speaker, I added my trying solution now.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'high performance'? How large can the list be? If it's only 1000 or so numbers, then it won't really matter what algorithm you use.

Comment: sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a higher performing solution, but I used a combination of set comprehension and set operations, which are typically fast. The first line creates a set of the list which removes duplicates. In addition, there is a condition to create the set with positive integers in that list only. The second statement takes a difference between numbers in that range and your list. This is faster than sorting as sorting takes n^2 time, while set creation is n time. Since we don't care about repetitive value we can use set methods.

```
lis_1 = [-4, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
lis_2 = [-3, -9, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5]
def find_least_not_in(l):
    s_l = {x for x in l if x > 0}
    return min(set(range(1,max(s_l)+1)).difference(s_l))
print "Case 1: ", find_least_not_in(lis_1)
print "Case 2: ", find_least_not_in(lis_2)
```

Here is the output when I ran it:

```
=================== RESTART: C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/stack.py ===================
Case 1:  1
Case 2:  4
>>>
```